# Variadic Tuples Implementation

Tags: c++11, tuples

I've been trying to use Variadic Tuples on Generic Templates and Structs. The idea is to obtain the max and sum of a variadic tuple. So far I was able to obtain the required results but had to use Global static variables. I've posted the code below of the implementation.

```
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <complex>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <tuple>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::complex_literals;

    template<typename T>
    static T max;

    template<typename T>
    static T sum;

    template<typename T>
    static T average;

    template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t N>
    struct Calculator
    {
    static void maximum(const Tuple& pack)
    {
    Calculator<T, Tuple, N - 1>::maximum(pack);
    T packValue = get<N - 1>(pack);
    if (packValue > max<T>)
    {
    //T max = get<0>(pack);
    //Try the above instead of the below code to calculate max
    max<T> = get<N - 1>(pack);
    }
    }

    static void summation(const Tuple& pack)
    {
    Calculator<T, Tuple, N - 1>::summation(pack);
    T packValue = get<N - 1>(pack);
    sum<T> += packValue;
    }

    static void averager(const Tuple& pack)
    {
    average<T> = sum<T> / N;
    }


    };

    template<typename T, typename Tuple>
    struct Calculator<T, Tuple, 1>
    {
    static void maximum(const Tuple& pack)
    {
    //T max = get<0>(pack);
    //Try the above instead of the below code to calculate max
    max<T> = get<0>(pack);
    }

    static void summation(const Tuple& pack)
    {
    sum<T> = get<0>(pack);
    }
    };




    int main()
    {
    tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double, double> t1 = make_tuple(16565.256, 45.539,     0.25, 1000.25, 1.25036, 35.66, 210.20);

    Calculator<double, tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double, double>, 7>::maximum(t1);

    cout << "Maximum is: " << max<double> << endl;

    Calculator<double, tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double, double>, 7>::summation(t1);
    cout << "Total Sum is: " << sum<double> << endl;

    Calculator<double, tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double, double>, 7>::averager(t1);
    cout << "Average is: " << average<double> << endl;



    std::complex<int> c2(22, 3);
    std::complex<int> ci(15, 41);
    tuple<std::complex<int>, std::complex<int> > ct1 = make_tuple(ci, c2);

    Calculator< std::complex<int>, tuple<std::complex<int>, std::complex<int> >, 2>::summation(ct1);

    cout << "Summation of complex numbers is: " << sum<std::complex<int>> << endl;

    }
```

My question, is it possible to implement a version that doesn't use Global static variables to hold the values of sum and max but an alternate implementation using Variadic Templates and Structs if possible?

Comment: this type of question might be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You use *variable template*, so you have at least C++14. In C++14 you can use `index_sequence` as easy way to extract all tuple items and rewrite your recursion functions to be non-recursive:

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t N>
struct Calculator
{
template<size_t ... Indices>
static T maxHelper(const Tuple& pack, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)  {
    return std::max( {std::get<Indices>(pack)...} );
} // [1]

static T maximum(const Tuple& pack)  {
    return maxHelper(pack, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}); 
}

template<size_t ... Indices>
static T sumHelper(const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)  {
    T arr[] = { std::get<Indices>(t)... }; // [2]
    return std::accumulate(arr,arr+N,T{}); // [3]
}

static T summation(const Tuple& pack) {
    return sumHelper(pack,std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
};
```

in [1] tuple's items are extracted into `std::initializer_list`, then `std::max` overload taking that list is called.

in [2] and [3] tuple's items are extracted into array, and summing is done by `std::accumulate`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5KcUjr)

---

Since of C++17 use `std::apply` (and *fold expression* for summing):

```
template<class ... Args>
auto maxValue(std::tuple<Args...> t) {
    return std::apply( [](auto&&... args) { return std::max({args...}); },t);
}

template<class ... Args>
auto sumValue(std::tuple<Args...> t) {
    return std::apply( [](auto&&... args){ return (args + ...);} , t);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HgN_k7)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed alternate solution. Just started using Variadic Tuples and Variadic Templates but was running into some issues. This solution is helping to increase my understanding on the subject matter. Thank you very much.